Cohomology of the sheaf of invertible rational functions
Let $X$ be an irreducible algebraic variety. Recall that the group of Cartier divisors is defined to be $H^0(X,\mathcal M_X^\times/\mathcal O_X^\times)$, where $\mathcal M_X^\times$ denotes the sheaf of non-zero rational functions on $X$ under multiplication. The Picard group of $X$ is $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^\times)$. Consider the short exact sequence
$$
0\to\mathcal O_X^\times\to \mathcal M_X^\times\to \mathcal M_X^\times/\mathcal O_X^\times\to 0
$$
The induced long exact sequence of cohomology is
$$
H^0(X,\mathcal M_X^\times/\mathcal O_X^\times) \to Pic(X) \to H^1(\mathcal M_X^\times)\to H^1(\mathcal M_X^\times/\mathcal O_X^\times).
$$
The map $H^0(X,\mathcal M_X^\times/\mathcal O_X^\times) \to Pic(X)$ is surjective. Is it because $H^1(X,\mathcal M_X^\times)$ vanishes? And what about higher cohomology groups $H^i(X,\mathcal M_X^\times)$? Do they vanish as well?

Isn't this a constant sheaf? (Which is flasque and hence has vanishing higher cohomology.)
